# Swipe up Gesture is not working inside Scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement to swipe gestures inside child layout of scroll view.Swipe left,right and down are working fine but when i am trying to swipe up the view scrolls and swipe up gesture doesn't work.

Can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: You need to post your code so we can see what went wrong

Comment: How did you set your onTouchListener? Can you post your code?